# React access DOM element instead of object thru refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to access DOM element in react because it need for third party library.
And I'm able to do it with refs for built in react elems.
Like `<div ref={this.someRef}` `<span ref={this.otherRef}` etc.

And I can access DOM elem thru `this.someRef.current`
But when I'm trying to do same trick for custom elements `<SomeCustomElem ref={this.anotherRef}`, `this.anotherRef.current` returns me an object of values and I dont see any way to access DOM elem with custom components.

Is there any chance to get access to DOM of custom elem?

Comment: btw what does that 3rd party library you want to use? if it modifies DOM of elements given all its changes will be rewritten on next `render()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `react-dom` to access any type of DOM element which is shipped with `react`.

To access the DOM  pass a `ref` with  the react element and latter access it with [findDOMNode](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) method.

Example:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

...  

let reactElement = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.refName)

...  

<Component ref='refName'/>
```

Comment: `ref='refName'` syntax is deprecated.

Comment: `findDOMNode` is also deprecated in strict mode: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#warning-about-deprecated-finddomnode-usage

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what kind of component `SomeCustomElem` is.

For `<SomeCustomElem ref={this.anotherRef}/>`, ReactDOM [`findDOMNode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) can be used:

```
findDOMNode(this.anotherRef.current);
```

This cannot be done if `SomeCustomElem` is functional component. Neither `ref` nor `findDOMNode` will work on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(<Any React Element>)  //Returns a DOM node 


//eg. Using "this" inside a react el.
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).scrollIntoView()
```

Make sure to try-catch it as it might return null

Answer (score 0):

findDOMNode [is suggested to avoid](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode):

> findDOMNode is an escape hatch used to access the underlying DOM node. In most cases, use of this escape hatch is discouraged because it pierces the component abstraction.

You can [forward ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) instead.

But just think about that in a way "`ref` links you to given component". So maybe you just [use separated prop](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1a018a023347fe1c2476073330cc5509) like that:

```
class CustomComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<div ref={this.props.outerDivRef}> .... </div>);
    }
}

class Parent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.innerRef = React.createRef();
    }

    render() {
        return (<CustomComponent outerDivRef={this.innerRef} />);
    }
}
```

Besides last pattern is older than ref forwarding feature but it looks like more flexible one.